# multer Cannot read property 'path' of undefined when upload image from iPhone gallery

Tags: ios, node.js, express, multer

I use multer to do ajax upload in my project, and I use FormData in front-end to do ajax upload.

I am testing in my iPhone 5s

My Problem is when I click my `input[type="file"]`, and I choose take picture, it can be successfully uploaded.

**BUT when I choose from my gallery, and select a picture I took before, the upload program crashed**

this problem will just cause in iPhone, but not in Android or PC

```
\routes\index.js:128

filename: req.file.path.replace(/public/, '')
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\routes\index.js:128:23
    at Array.<anonymous> (E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:52:37)
    at listener (E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (E:\GraduationProject\jnstagram\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:383:13)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:407:11)
```

my server side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');

var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function() {

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'public/uploads');
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            var name = file.originalname;
            var dot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            cb(null, name.slice(0, dot) + '-' + new Date().getTime() + name.slice(dot));
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
            if (/\.(png|jpg)$/i.test(file.originalname)) {
                cb(null, true);
            } else {
                cb(null, false);
            }
        }
    });

    var fileUpload = upload.single('file');

    router.post('/ajaxupload', function(req, res) {
        fileUpload(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'upload failed'
                });
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                success: true,
                filename: req.file.path.replace(/public/, '')
            });
        });
    });

    return router;

};
```

my client side upload code:

```
var fd = new ForData();
fd.append('file', this.refs.myFile.files[0]); // use React refs
request
    .post('/ajaxupload')
    .send(fd)
    .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
           // do something
    });
```

Comment: What library are you using on the client side for sending the request?

Comment: could you check whether the file got uploaded to your `public/uploads` folder, if yes, then it `req.file` object is there. But as per the error `req.file` is undefined.

Comment: @mscdex it's superagent

Comment: @Nivesh file didn't upload successfully, because the program is already crashed. Do you have an iPhone to test, select the image you captured before in you gallery. This problem only occurs in iPhone, I've tried several device.